# Let me know that how can i connect to sql server in monodroid without creating web service.

Tags: xamarin.android

Let me know that how can i connect to sql server in monodroid without creating web service.

Answer (score 1):

Mono for Android includes the [System.Data.dll](http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Assemblies) assembly, which includes [System.Data.SqlClient namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) support (just like [MonoTouch does](http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/System.Data)). To use Mono for Android's `System.Data.SqlClient` implementation you'll need to enable TDS support on your SQL Server instance; see also my handy [Microsoft SQL Server Setup guide](http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/mono/2009/May-14.html#nerddinner-sqlserver-configuration) for connecting to SQL Server from Mono's `System.Data.SqlClient` implementation (some of which may be useful to you).

Answer (score 0):

If you find an open-source type 4 JDBC [(I here jTDS does this, though I have not personal experience)](http://jtds.sourceforge.net) driver for SQL Server it shouldn't be too difficult to port to Android; you'll still hit problems on many devices, though, for cell network providers aren't always good about allowing traffic to "unusual" ports from cell devices.